# bash - How can I escape double quotes inside brackets inside double quotes?

Tags: bash, quotes, double-quotes

I want to provide an argument with spaces to a function in the second argument of printf inside a git alias.

```
git config --global alias.foo '!a="C:\New folder"; printf "%s\n" "$(basename $a)"'
git config --global alias.foo '!a="C:\New folder"; printf "%s\n" "$(basename \"$a\")"'
git config --global alias.foo '!a="C:\New folder"; printf "%s\n" "$(basename "\""$a"\"")"'

git config --global alias.foo '!a="C:\New folder"; b=$(basename "$a"); printf "%s\n" "$b"'
```

The first three yield `New`. The last one avoids the issue and yields `New folder` as intended. How can I write the alias without using an additional variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. This should work fine:

```
git config --global alias.foo '!a="C:\New folder"; printf "%s\n" "$(basename "$a")"'
```

Comment: Reason: the command substitution starts a new quoting context in the shell code: double quotes inside will not close the double-quoted string that contains the command substitution.